# Hamcrest: how how I can check is it Integer type or not in API response

Tags: java, api, automated-tests, rest-assured, hamcrest

For example I have json response:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Test",
        "subtitle": null,
        "description": null,

        "latitude": "59.49239000",
        "longitude": "10.31197000",
        "radius": 10,
```

How can I validate for example that 'radius' accept only Ineger values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can evaluate [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) as it is much better than REST-assured for light-weight / one-off schema validation. And you can even do this for all array elements in one-shot:

```
* def data = { foo: [{ bar: 1, baz: 'a' }, { bar: 2, baz: 'b' }, { bar: 3, baz: 'c' }]}
* match each data.foo == { bar: '#number', baz: '#string' }
```